# Content Security Policy error while integrating Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using the following configuration (using Node.js and Express)

```
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.stripe.com', 'https://checkout.stripe.com'],
    styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.googleapis.com'],
    imgSrc: ["'self'", 'data:', 'https://*.stripe.com'],
    fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https://fonts.gstatic.com'],
    connectSrc: ["'self'", 'https://api.stripe.com', 'https://checkout.stripe.com'],
    frameAncestors: ["'none'"],
    frameSrc: ["'self'", 'https://js.stripe.com', 'https://hooks.stripe.com', 'https://checkout.stripe.com'],
    childSrc: ["'self'"],
    baseUri: ["'self'"],
    formAction: ["'self'"]
  }
}));
```

But I still get the CSP error.

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://js.stripe.com/v3/ (“script-src”).

I have been tinkering with it for a few day with no luck. So any help would be massive. Thank you